# Distribution of a Chrome extension through an application - is a "backup" OK?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My company distributes a Chrome extension along with our Windows apps. I have read the Google guidelines on doing so, [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions), and see that the recommended method of doing so is to publish the extension in the Chrome Web Store, which we have done. Then, during installation, we should place a key in the Windows registry, which will direct Chrome to download the extension from the store the next time it starts up. This all makes sense, and we are planning to use this method.

**However,** I am told by some of our developers that they are worried about certain scenarios (specifically in countries where access to Google servers may be blocked) where it may not be possible to install the extension this way. Therefore, they have proposed both using this method, and including the .crx file in our installation package. My question is: **Will this cause any issues?** For users with a normal connection to Google's servers, will they be able to receive the extension as normal?

Comment: Users will not be able to install .crx files. You will need to provide a folder or zip and direct them to load via developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this cause any issues?

As long as "it's useless, because it can't be installed" isn't an issue, *then no, no issues including it.* /sarcasm

You cannot install CRX files from third-party sources, even manually (and not at all automatically), with the possible exception of [enterprise deployment via domain policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

The only way to install a non-Store extension is as unpacked. This requires manually switching on the Developer mode, selecting the folder, and enduring the scary warning on every Chrome launch.

I'm afraid you'll need to consider excluding such scenarios from your potential market.

Comment: Didn't you used to be able to host your extensions on your own website? I'm fairly sure I remember doing that years ago as a student to postpone paying the 10 euro one off fee...

Comment: Yes, keyword "used to". See [this](https://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html), for instance. The situation changed in May 2014 due to rampant malware.

Comment: To be honest, that's how I thought it works... but our developers keep saying that they can install the plugin directly. Maybe they all have Chrome in developer mode or something...

Comment: You can install a CRX you packed locally. But it won't work with CRX packaged by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

### How to local install ALL Chrome CRX without any problem:

Chrome saves ALL information in `%LocalAppData%\Google`.

1. Install Chrome
2. Install Chrome .CRX you are needing
3. Back up `%LocalAppData%\Google`
4. Create WinRar to unpack saved profile to: `%LocalAppData%`

This bypasses the mandatory Chrome store installation.
What are the downsides of this method?

1. Using this method could overwrite existing user profile data/bookmarks.
2. Overwriting user saved bookmarks/passwords may cause data loss for user.

What is a possible workaround?

1. Firefox can use alternate profile, if set to do so via txt in user profile.
2. If Chrome profile can load alternate profile, locate the string/text responsible for this & edit it to use the new user profile path, then create a WinRar SFX to install to this new location.
3. This will then enable Chrome SFX installer (Via WinRar SFX) to install a chrome profile with the .CRX extensions desired already installed & not have to mess with pre-existing user data.

What are the downsides to this method?

1. Users may wonder how to get their old bookmarks/settings to work.
2. While users will get the new .CRX, it will be starting with essentially a blank profile.

How you can help:

1. We know we can install any unpacked CRX via SFX install.
2. We know we can potentially cause Chrome to use alternate profile to avoid corrupting or messing with user data.
3. We need someone with an idea how to install unpacked CRX without causing a problem in the old user profile.

Things tried so far:

1. Tried to locate the file(s) responsible for saving installed .CRX settings.
   (Make unpacked CRX load & work properly)
2. Discovered a key file that contained bookmarks/user data also was the same one responsible for ID the CRX & making it load.
3. This presented a problem, because how is it possible to import this key file in a WinRar SFX installer, without also overwriting the user bookmarks/saved data?

If anyone can figure this part out, we can then use WinRar SFX to unpack CRX into Chrome profile directory, without overwriting/destroying user data.

Alternate method may be to re-route Chrome to use new profile with desired .CRX files already loaded, then cmd-line import the old profile settings/bookmarks/saved passwords.

If this is possible...

Congrats to all who are seeking solutions!
Working together, we can succeed!